# I want a input which has a button besides it

Tags: html, forms, redirect, input

I want a input which has a button besides it, and whenever I click on the button it takes me to a location(to be precise : "https://localhost:5000/message/to={{inputbyuser}}") where {{inputbyuser}} is the input which the user has entered. Also as I will be hosting  it later I want not the localhost to come but the webpage to get it's own domain. Is there a way?
My HTML snippet:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the username to chat : " class="input-required"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
```

And yes the send button is a icon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

First, give the button an ID of `submit_btn` and the input field an ID of `input_field`, then, add some JavaScript on the end of your page:

```
document.getElementById("submit_btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const input_value = document.getElementById("input_field").value;

    window.location.href = `https://localhost:5000/message/to=${input_value}`;
});
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: But if I depoy it online then will the href work? I was looking for some solution by which the app get's its domain and send request to it. I dont want to write https://localhost:5000